# Can I play Destiny 2 without PS Plus?

Tags: destiny-2

Can I play Destiny 2: Forsaken without a PS Plus subscription?

Some of my friends say I can't but then others say I can and I went to EB games but the worker there was useless.

Answer (score 10):

You can play Destiny 2 without PS Plus however most of the game modes and features will not be available.

You will be able to do:

- Story missions for the main Destiny 2 campaign and each of the DLC's you own.
- Planet activities such as Adventures, Patrols, Public Events & Lost Sectors but on your own, no other players will join you.

You will not be able to do the following:

- Strikes
- Raids
- Crucible PvP
- Gambit PvEvP
- Forges
- Reckoning
- Menagerie
- Vex Offensive
- Nightmare Hunts
- Join fireteams with other players

Even though you can do things like public events, these are designed to be completed by groups and will be difficult on your own.

The stuff you will not be able to do includes most of the late game content and IMO the real fun and rewarding part of playing Destiny 2.

My advice is that you need a PS Plus subscription to make Destiny 2 worthwhile.

Edit 1: Alternatively you can play on PC where online play is available without a subscription, however there is no cross play if your friends are on another platform and you will need a PC powerful enough to run it.

Edit 2: Destiny 2 New Light is now available for free so you can try out a lot of the content to help you decide.

Edit 3: Destiny 2 starting season 15 —which is now— finally has cross-play fully enabled. you can jump on Bungie's website and enable cross-save and add your steam account. You can then open the game on steam and add friends on console using the "Bungie Name" which is similar to a discord tag (User#1234). simply invite or join others, Cross-play is fully functional and has finally arrived. No need for console subscriptions.

Comment: "PC powerful enough to run it." -> That is key, but that said - Destiny 2 is very good at optimizations, and it runs okay even on (modern) starter gaming PCs. Unless you're trying to run it on a potato, you shouldn't have issues.

Comment: Well not all content is available on the pc, you still have to buy the expansions